# restful webservices @DELETE 405 error

Tags: java, rest, jaxb

I have this code to provide deletion of a player with specific id:

```
    @DELETE
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("/delPlayer/{pid}")
    public int deleteById(@PathParam("pid") Integer pid){
        TypedQuery<Player> q = em.createQuery("DELETE p FROM Player p WHERE p.pid = :c", Player.class);
return q.setParameter("c", pid).executeUpdate();
    }
```

when I open `http://localhost:8080/Project/r/Player/delPlayer/100` in browser I get

```
HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed
type Status report
messageMethod Not Allowed
descriptionThe specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't open that method using the browser as the browser will open the URL using GET not DELETE, You should create a simple method to call it using the right verb, or also, you can call it using cURL from a unix shell

Comment: i dont understand I made this changed anotation to GET and call another metod anotated with DELETE